# How do I turn this code using a simple map function?

Tags: perl

I am still learning how to use the map command, and am having trouble figuring out how to convert the following the following code from the following to using the map command:

**One-Liner**

```
perl -MData::Dumper -wE'
   $_ = "Alpha,Beta,Gamma|Alpha,Beta";
   say;
   ($first,$second)=split/\|/;
   @first=split /,/,$first;
   @second=split /,/, $second;
   print Dumper({FIRST=>\@first, SECOND=>\@second})
'
```

**Full script:**

```
#! /usr/bin/perl  
use strict; 
use warnings; 
use Data::Dumper;
use v5.10; 

$_ = "Alpha,Beta,Gamma|Alpha,Beta";

say;

my ($first,$second)=split/\|/; 
my @first=split /,/,$first; 
my @second=split /,/, $second; 
warn Dumper({FIRST=>\@first, SECOND=>\@second});
```

**I want the line below to be converted to two arrays using the map function instead:**

Alpha,Beta,Gamma|Alpha,Beta

```
$VAR1 = {
          'FIRST' => [
                       'Alpha',
                       'Beta',
                       'Gamma'
                     ],
          'SECOND' => [
                        'Alpha',
                        'Beta'
                      ]
        };
```

Comment: Your data already is converted to two arrays. You are combining them into an anonymous hash which you are passing to D::D but there are two arrays here, `@first` and `@second`.

Comment: Sorry will change it so you can read it easier..  I agree.

Comment: Also, it is not clear what you would gain by using `map` here.

Comment: Maybe using a map would not be helpful.

Comment: You can add the option `-MO=Deparse` to that one liner to make it easier to read

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
perl -MData::Dumper -wle'
  $_ = "Alpha,Beta,Gamma|Alpha,Beta"; 
  print;
  my @r = 
      # map { my @x = split /,/; \@x } 
      map { [split /,/] } # same functionality as above
      split/\|/; 
  warn Dumper \@r;
'
```

and for exact output as above (Dumper href)

```
perl -MData::Dumper -wle'
  $_ = "Alpha,Beta,Gamma|Alpha,Beta"; 
  print;
  my %h =
      map { qw(FIRST SECOND)[$i++] => [split /,/] }
      split/\|/; 
  warn Dumper \%h;
'
```

Comment: Thank you, I was so close to understanding this.  I see now I threw everyone off using Dumper to represent as a hash, when all I wanted was to compare two arrays after the map command.

Comment: @Alliswell then `warn Dumper [ \@first, \@second ];` should be better choice

Comment: @Alliswell is there something wrong with answer?

Comment: @mpaoec no sorry, getting used to posting and Stackoverflow.  All is well with your answer! I really appreciate your help!

Answer (score 4):

The repeated part is the split on commas, the creation of an array, assigning to that array and getting a reference to that array (`my @first = split /,/, $first; \@first`), so this is what's going to be inside the loop (`my @a = split /,/, $_; \@a` aka `[ split /,/ ]`).

```
my %h; @h{qw( FIRST SECOND )} = map [ split /,/ ], split /\|/;
```

Buy why are you using a hash? An array would be much more natural.

```
my @a = map [ split /,/ ], split /\|/;
```

With the latter, you'd use `$a[0]` and `$a[1]` instead of `$h{FIRST}` and `$h{SECOND}`.

Comment: I am very new to using Data::Dumper and map so I was using it as an example to print out the arrays subdivided. I saw this as an example once by another Perl programmer. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Dumper usage is pretty simple:: `print(Dumper($scalar));`, `print(Dumper(\%hash));` or `print(Dumper(\@array));`